Shalom Zachar - why the name?
The practice of having a Shalom Zachar is throwing a kiddush soon after a male baby is born, in celebration, held by Ashkenazi Jews, and it is even codified in Shulchan Aruch.
The wikipedia page is decent enough but I am interested in knowing why, specifically, it is called "Shalom Zachar", which can mean "hello male" or "welcoming a male" or "peace upon this male" etc, and it's a curious phrase.

I don't think I would call it a kiddush

lol, didn't think to search for "zochor". @JoelK you are right, I used the term way too colloquially

@RabbiKaii Even more painful: Shalom Zachor. shudder
